# Returning null from a get inside of a class

Tags: c#

I have the following in my model:

```
    public string Subject { 
        get { 
            return SubjectReference.GetSubject(SubjectID);
        }
    }
```

How can I make this so that if the SubjectID is null then the get call will return null? I think there's a way to do this with the ? operator but can I use this inside of a class for model properties?

Comment: You can use the ternary operator `?` or just an `if` statement.

Comment: @Andre technically the conditional operator. While there is only one ternary operator is C#, it doesn't mean there won't be another in the future.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich that's as unconstructive as saying: "There is a typo in your comment, you probably meant '**in** C#'".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
public string Subject
{
   get
   {
       return SubjectID == null ? null : SubjectReference.GetSubject(SubjectID);
   }
}
```

You could consider `string.IsNullOrEmpty(SubjectID)` instead when an empty string for `SubjectID` should also result in a `null` return.

If your property is a reference type then of course `null` is a legal return value.

Comment: so would the following be okay: return string.IsNullOrEmpty(SubjectID) ? null : SubjectReference.GetSubject(SubjectID);

Comment: @Melissa Yes that would be ok.

Answer (score 3):

You may use either a regular `if` statement, or the *ternary operator* (`?` operator) as you've mentioned.  Examples of each are provided below.

---

**Using an if statement:**

```
public string Subject { 
    get { 
        if (SubjectID == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return SubjectReference.GetSubject(SubjectID);
    }
}
```

**Using ternary operator:**

```
public string Subject { 
    get { 
        return SubjectID == null ? null : SubjectReference.GetSubject(SubjectID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
public string Subject { 
    get { 
        return SubjectID==null ? null : SubjectReference.GetSubject(SubjectID);
    }
}
```